# Apply freeze to excel files using macro for multiple files in folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder in that will receive 30 files every day and the file contains multiple sheets and in those sheets, some header starts with Row 1 and some with Row 5. I need apply freeze based on the row header name and I need to run the macro from outside of the folder.
After applying freeze I need to automate the process to send the files to the client.

I tried with below but getting error

> "type mismatch souceVBAProject"

```vb
Sub FreezePanes()

Call freeze("*.xlsx", "no")
End Sub

Sub freeze(fileName As String, hide As String)

Dim path As String
Dim srcFile As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
 path = "C:\Users\RadhaRani\Desktop\Excel\"
 srcFile = fileName

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rng As Range
Dim wks As Workbook
Set wks = Workbooks.Open(path + srcFile)

Set wks = Application.ActiveSheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    ws.Select
    Set rng = ActiveCell
    Range("A5").Select '<== set Freeze point here
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    rng.Select
Next
wks.Select

ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
wks.Close
Set wks = Nothing
```

Comment: If you have headers on row 5, you want to use row 6 to set your `FreezePanes`

Comment: `Set wks = Workbooks.Open(path + srcFile)` is problematic because you should use `&` to concatenate, not `+`, and more importantly, `Workbooks.Open` doesn't work with wildcards. One option is to use `Dir` to get the filename.

Answer (score 0):

'If you have shut off ScreenUpdating, you must turn it back on by placing---Application.ScreenUpdating = True---at the top of the code

The top 5 rows are frozen; *Note:* use the row below the header row.

```
Application.Goto Cells(6, 1)
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```